Nerve Impulse Process
In the process of re-polarization, when we have achieved the normal membrane potential, why does K+ voltage gate dont close at -70mv and rather at -90mv when its hyper-polarized?

There is a key difference in Na+ and K+ ion channels:  Na+ channels are quick to open and inactivate, while K+ channels are both slow to open and close.
Shortly after the peak of depolarization is reached, the inactivation gate structure of Na+ channels stops the inflow of Na+. However, the voltage gated K+ channels that have been activated by depolarization allow the membrane to repolarize from K+ outflow.
The K+ channels are slow to close and thus they allow some more K+ to escape (afterhyperpolarization) before finally closing.

They do, but they are slow to change state and the membrane voltage is changing quickly.
You can think of ion channel gating like a chemical reaction, with the channel in equilibrium between different states: open and closed (and frequently other types of states as well, like "inactivated"; there can also be multiple distinct open and closed states).
Like a chemical reaction, in addition to the concept of "equilibrium" (what would be the average state of the channels given a very long time) there is also "rate": how long does it take to get to equilibrium.
The equilibrium of closed versus open voltage-gated channels is, by definition, a function of voltage, but equilibrium is not reached instantly. In the Hodgkin-Huxley model, the rates $\alpha$ and $\beta$ represent the opening and closing reaction rates. I'd highly encourage playing around with a Hodgkin-Huxley simulation and tweaking those parameters to see the results.
